# Include a grid framework in visual studio that seems to be linux only?

Tags: visual-studio, compass-sass, susy-compass, susy-sass, susy

I use Visual Studio 2013 with Web Essentials extension for all my Sass/Scss work. Its great.

I came across a tutorial on a grid framework that I really want to use called [Susy](https://github.com/ericam/susy). However the tutorials I seen on it are all using it on Linux or mac and in some sort of a ruby based environment.

Even on the site link, I don't see instructions on getting it to work in VS2013. I tried extension manager and nuget package manager but to no avail.

My only option seems to be to download the source and try to compile it by combining all the Scss files and hoping I do it in the right order. But something tells me I am getting a bit over complicated and there is a simpler way.

There are many ruby/Linux based libraries like this and I really would like to know how to bring this into VS2013 and later I can do it for any of the libraries I want.

I am sure that people making the tutorials for such libraries (and the libraries themselves) are not excluding VS2013 purposefully (if at all). I just don't know how to get them into VS2013.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you already using Sass? If so, how?

Comment: @EricMSuzanne - In visual studio 2013 update 3, especially if you include the web essentials extension. You simply create a .scss/.sass file and web essentials takes care of the translation to css. You have 2 windows side by side, the sass and the translated css. Then I simply bundle my css file in the bundles.config which takes care of the minification. All that's left is to use it as normal in the header.

Comment: +1 I have VS2013 update 2 with web essentials and I was unable to include susy. Web essentials may have trouble compiling it?

Comment: @FrancisRodgers So did you get Eric's solution to work?  Can we get an update?

Comment: @JasonFrank - I have since moved on to another project and left that far behind. However, I do believe SO requires me to accept an answer if it works. So I will check out his solution this weekend and let you know by Tue at latest.

Comment: @JasonFrank - I tried to include it again. However unfortunately I cannot yet accept Erics answer because I am unable to verify if it works. It appears that in the recent update to Web Essentials they have *Again* removed support for Sass/Scss. So this wont compile to CSS. However if this changes, I will take another look down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Susy anywhere you use Sass. Rather than using a gem bundle, or any of the other linux-based approaches, copy and paste the entire Susy sass directory into your own sass directory, then import it into your stylesheets. You can treat all of Susy like any other sass partial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It will be a week or so before I am working on that project again, so I'll let you know if I was able to get it working. Thanks again.

Comment: Susy does require Sass 3.3+ so you'll have to find out if VS supports a recent version of Sass.