# How to include Susy sass framework with Web Essentials

Tags: web-essentials

I tried to make simple web solution - a hello world solution - with the [susy responsive toolkit](https://github.com/ericam/susy/blob/master/docs/index.rst). The instructions on the [susy docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/#simple-install) say to pull the sass folder in, but the sass doesn't seem to compile.

It is possible to get susy 2.2 to work in VS w/ web essentials?

I'm using VS2013 update 3 with web essentials.

I'd really appreciate it if somebody could upload a 'hello world' working solution. And so would [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404053/include-a-grid-framework-in-visual-studio-that-seems-to-be-linux-only).

Additional Info for non-VS users:
Web essentials usually 'compiles' sass into css files. 
[image]

Web essentials also has a menu option to compile the sass.
[image]

Once I uncomment the import statement, the sass no longer compiles or refreshes. No error message is shown. I'm pretty sure this is a web essentials plugin or web essentials dependancy problem.

Comment: I don't know visual studio, but I'm curious what you mean by "the sass doesn't seem to compile". Did you import the Susy partials in your main stylesheets? Are you getting an error? What error do you see? Note that Susy 2 requires Sass 3.3+.

Comment: @EricMSuzanne I don't have enough experience to debug this properly. Its probably a Sass support or version problem per http://webessentials.uservoice.com/forums/140520-general/suggestions/6208898-update-sass-to-version-3-3

Answer (score 0):

At this time, VS web exetensions probably uses a sass compiler does does not meet the susy2.1's sass 3.3+ requirement.

The sass folder in the susy2.1 project compiles okay when compiled with [koala](https://github.com/oklai/koala) - which supports sass version 3.3.7 as of writing.

Comment: I was unable to find an easy VS way. If you want to dig in enough, theres some really nice tutorials to set up simple node.js grunt workflow with sass - which makes it very easy to include and work with susy.
http://matthew-jackson.com/notes/development/setting-up-grunt-from-scratch/
http://matthew-jackson.com/notes/development/grunt-workflow-for-sass-compass-and-js/

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is an issue with libSass and @import not working as expected. The author notes it [here](http://anotheruiguy.roughdraft.io/46a9c2e8682ea5cf0acf-why-libsass-is-important-to-the-community) and links to libSass issues [here](http://anotheruiguy.roughdraft.io/8794442-where-extended-placeholder-selectors-go-wrong-in-libsass)